# Most efficient way to solve a system of linear equations

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

I have an (n x n) symmetric matrix A and a (n x 1) vector B.  Basically, I just need to solve Ax = b for x.  The issue is that A is going to potentially be massive.  So I'm looking for the most efficient algorithm for solving linear equations in C++.  I looked over the Eigen library.  Apparently it has an SVD method, but I've been told it's slow.  Solving x=inverse(A)*b also seems like it would be suboptimal.  Is uBLAS faster? Are there any more efficient methods?  Thanks.

Edit: matrix A is positive definite and not sparse.

Comment: Umm... Gaussian elimination?

Comment: Is your matrix positive definite? Then (P)CG might be an option for you. Other than that, have a look at iterative methods (Gauss-Seidel, Jacobi and so on) instead of direct solver if your system is too large.

Comment: What is your average matrix size? Is your matrix sparse?

Comment: Speaking from personal experience, stability is a much greater concern than speed.  Not much point in a fast solver when it produces garbage numbers and real world problems are often unstable.  Gaussian sucked, it accumulates rounding error badly, got excellent results from LU decomposition.  Not much point left in spinning your own anymore, try them all and don't forget to look for correct results.

Comment: This should be the right thing for you: [Eigen Cholesky](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Cholesky__Module.html) (maybe, the variant with pivoting for stability).

Comment: If your matrices are huge but well-conditioned then you can use [iterative techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) and [incomplete Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_Cholesky_factorization) as pre-conditioner. That should be faster than any complete factorization for well-conditioned matrices.

Comment: Also, don't invert A and then multiply by B. Use a method (like Eigen's `solve()`) that solves the whole system more efficiently.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The best way to solve a system of linear equations of the form `Ax = b` is to do the following.

- decompose `A` into the format `A = M1 * M2` (where `M1` and `M2` are triangular)
- Solve `M1 * y = b` for `y` using back substitution
- Solve `M2 * x = y` for `x` using back substitution

For **square matrices**, step 1 would use [LU Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition).

For **non square matrices**, step 1 would use [QR Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition).

If matrix A is **positive definite and not sparse** you'd use [Cholesky Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) for the first step.

If you want to use eigen, you will have to first [decompose it](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LLT.html) and then [triangular solve](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1TriangularView.html#aa4a11ffc4c8895aaec7ca00668e18c84) it.

If this is still slow, thankfully, there are numerous linear algebra libraries available that can help improve the performance. The routine you should be looking for is `dpotrs`. Some libraries that have this implemented are as follows:

- Netlib's lapack: [Documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dpotrs.f) and [Download](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/#_lapack_version_3_5_0_2) (free)
- Intel's MKL: [Documentation](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-2039BD5D-44D1-487A-9B68-87BD46019A5F.htm) and [Download](http://software.intel.com/en-us/non-commercial-software-development) (Free for non commercial use).
- AMD's ACML: [Download](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/cpu-development/amd-core-math-library-acml/acml-downloads-resources/) (free)
- PLASMA: [Download](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/plasma/) (free, multi core optimized)
- MAGMA : [Download](http://icl.utk.edu/magma/) (free, Implemented in CUDA, OpenCL)
- CULA: [Download](http://www.culatools.com/downloads/dense/) (freemium, Implemented in CUDA).

If you are using eigen in the overall project, you can interface the LAPACK routine you need as described [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Lapack).

Comment: Excellent answer. There is also Eigen which is C++ header only lib:
Eigen::Matrix<double, N, N> A;
Eigen::Matrix<double, N, 1> b;
// ... load A, b
Eigen::Matrix<double, N, 1> x = A.fullPivLu().solve(b);
fullPivLU() does A = L*U but there are about 10 different decomposition you can choose from.