# Solve equation system Ax=b, A is binary. Is LU factorization still the fastest way?

Tags: matrix

Given the equation system Ax=b, where:

- Every field in A is either 0 or 1, except for the fields of the diagonal which are -1
- A is square and not singular
- x is always > 0 and b is always < 0

Is the fastest way to solve it still using LU factorization as described in this post: [Most efficient way to solve a system of linear equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181940/most-efficient-way-to-solve-a-system-of-linear-equations)?

Or is there some more efficient way thanks to the "binary" properties of A?

Comment: Its a good question, but I would be surprised if you could do much with the assumption that A is binary. For one thing, that is a fairly fragile assumption in that the very first row operation on such a matrix is likely to introduce values other than 0/1